# Why am I getting this timeout error when I return an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have a Silverlight app that is getting a list of items from a service on my website.  I am passing it as an ObservableCollection with the following function:

```
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> GetItems(string transetDocId)
    {
                    ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["ItemDataTable"]).Rows)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> tempD = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn dc in ((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["ItemDataTable"]).Columns)
                    tempD.Add(dc.ColumnName, dr[dc.ColumnName]);
                result.Add(tempD);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Everything *was* working fine.  And now, with no changes that I can think of, it has started returning the following error.

The HTTP request to 'http://www.example.com/Services/Example.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I've stepped through the code.  I'm firing off the GetItemsAsync() method in the client.  The service sees the call, creates the result and returns it. But the GetChecksCompleted() method never gets hit (Yes, I'm adding an event handler). After a few minutes, I get the error.

I tried modifying the code so that it returns one long comma/semicolon/pipe delimited string instead of an observable collection and everything runs fine.

Why won't the ObservableCollection work?

More information:
The error I'm getting actually occurs in the generated file Reference.cs in the line right before the return statement:

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>> EndGetItems(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>> _result = ((System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>)(base.EndInvoke("GetItems", _args, result)));
                return _result;
            }
```

Comment: I think that the ObservableCollection need a class that can be serialized, and the Dictionary can not.

Comment: @Aristos, is that a breaking change that was introduced in a recent patch?  Because this was working previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually with some of the data.  There was a DBNull value in some of the columns which was causing trouble during the deserialization.  The error message that it was throwing was just completely off.

I was able to figure out what was going on after enabling tracing as outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Thanks to anatoliiG for getting me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may happen when size of returned data exceeds Size Limit. Try to return only one element instead of all list to make sure that its not the reason. If it is - set needed maxBufferSize in config file.

Also posting your web.config may help.

Comment: The size wasn't actually the issue but this led me down the right path.  I'm going to post the solution but award you the bounty.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Perhaps you have too much data to return. Put a breakpoint on the server-side and see how many rows you've got there.
2. You actually don't have to return an ObservableCollection. WCF will return a
   list and it is up to your client to turn that into an ObservableCollection.

You can alter the client timeout.

```
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;

   /// <summary>
   /// Utility class for changing a domain context's WCF endpoint's
   /// SendTimeout. 
   /// </summary>
   public static class WcfTimeoutUtility
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the WCF endpoint SendTimeout for the specified domain
    /// context. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The domain context to modify.</param>
    /// <param name="sendTimeout">The new timeout value.</param>
    public static void ChangeWcfSendTimeout(DomainContext context, 
                                            TimeSpan sendTimeout)
    {
      PropertyInfo channelFactoryProperty =
        context.DomainClient.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelFactory");
      if (channelFactoryProperty == null)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
          "There is no 'ChannelFactory' property on the DomainClient.");
      }

      ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)
        channelFactoryProperty.GetValue(context.DomainClient, null);
      factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = sendTimeout;
    }
   }
```

Pass the domain context for the long-running operation and the new value for the send timeout to the ChangeWcfSendTimeout method, and you are good. You cannot change the binding after the endpoint is used, so the best place to call this method is in the domain context's partial OnCreated method, like this:

```
namespace SampleNamespace.Web.Services
{
  public partial class MyDomainContext
  {
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
      TimeSpan tenMinutes = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
      WcfTimeoutUtility.ChangeWcfSendTimeout(this, tenMinutes);
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Kyle McClennan [MSFT]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-change-the-request-timeout-for-wcf-ria-services.aspx)

Comment: I will try changing the timeout.  I know it doesn't have to be an observableCollection.  That wasn't even my first choice (DataTable), or second choice (List of custom objects) for that matter, it's just the best thing I could find that actually works with Silverlight. At least it DID work.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but I don't understand where these two classes should go. On the client or server side?

Comment: I can't get this to compile.    Two errors I'm getting are "type or namespace 'DomainContext' could not be found" and "cannot convert from 'MyDomainContext' to 'DomainContext'

Comment: The type or namespace name 'DomainServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Also, I think this might be a wild goose chase, as I don't think adjusting the timeout is going to work.  I'm not returning a large amount of data and the service call is completing quickly on the server side, it just never shows up back in the silverlight app

Comment: are you certain the server has returned the result? Can you run up Fiddler to observe that?

Comment: If you upload a simple test project somewhere, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to dispose your client connection. There is connection pool which has limited number of connections.When all connections are in use, the attempt to establish a new connection fails as I recall. Just wrap your channel to "using" statement.

Comment: This is happening on the very first call